# nm-connection-editor - command not found

Tags: linux, fedora-15

- HP Mini 210
- Fedora 15 Latest updates
- Gnome `3.0.1`

In the terminal when I do the following:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

I get the following:

```
command not found
```

Where is the `nm-connection-editor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nm-connection-editor` was part of the *network-manager-applet* package. GNOME 3 Shell has the network icon built in, so the applet package was removed from dependencies. You can still install it manually, though – the old applet should then be disabled via `gnome-session-properties`.

Also, it might be good to file a Fedora bug report, as the new GNOME "Network" settings panel won't work properly without `nm-connection-editor`.

Comment: When I went to install network-manager-applet it saids: No package network-manager-applet available. Thanks.

Comment: Try "NetworkManager-gnome".

Comment: Hello, Yes, I was able to install NetworkManager-gome and use the nm-connection-editor. However, one question. I am using Fedora 15 gnome 3.0.1. What is the difference between 'System Settings | Network' (I normally click this to edit my connections) and NetworkManager-gnome? Thanks

Comment: They both access the same NetworkManager settings. In fact, when you click on "Options..." in the System Settings page, you will launch the same `nm-connection-editor` from *NetworkManager-gnome*.